# What's the difference between using $a=(v2-v1)/t$ and $s=u\cdot t+1/2\cdot a\cdot t^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I have a coilgun shooting a projectile at initial velocity=0. We tracked the final velocity by dividing distance (0.5m) by time (0.13s) from exit of coilgun to impact 0.5m away with a camera.

So: v2=0.5/0.13, v1=0, s=0.5, t=0.13

Method 1 in title: acceleration appears to be distance/time^2, resulting in 29.58m/s^2.

Method 2: Using the constant acceleration equation above, the acceleration is calculated to be twice that, 59.16. Why?

Comment: Could you describe the experiment more clearly?  Initial velocity =0 seems to imply you are looking at the acceleration down the barrel.  You track the projectile for 0.5 m after leaving the barrel to find the exit velocity?  How long is the barrel?

Comment: You raised a really good point, thank you. We should have included the length of the barrel since that is what initial velocity=0 indicates. It makes sense to use that as the initial, the length of the barrel of the displacement, and the exit velocity (obtained with the tracking) as the final. Had we timed the projectile from current discharge to exit we could have obtained acceleration. (We've since changed the parameters of the experiment so that we only deal with dependent variable being kinetic energy 1/2mv^2 instead of force obtainable from acceleration and known mass.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two kinematic equations for constant acceleration that you have quote are correct.

If they are combined the error that you have made is revealed.

Substituting for the acceleration $a= \dfrac {v-u}{t}$ into the equation gives $s = ut + \dfrac 12 a t^2 \Rightarrow s = ut + \dfrac 12 \left( \dfrac {v-u}{t}\right) t^2 \Rightarrow s = \left (\dfrac {v+u}{2}\right )t$.

The quantity $ \left (\dfrac {v+u}{2}\right )$ is the **average** velocity over the time period $t$.

The velocity changes linearly from $u$ to $v$ during time $t$ whereas you have assumed that the velocity is constant at $v$ leading to the relationship $s = vt$ which would be correct if $u=v$ for all time.

Comment: How does this answer reconcile the "initial velocity =0" statement, and the "tracking ... from leaving the coil gun to impact" statement?

Answer (score 0):

this is because v is not equal to s/t. otherwise the equation of kinematic would be s=vt not s=ut+1/2 a t^2. you cant apply speed= distance/time unless you have constant acceleration

Answer (score -1):

You cannot calculate final velocity in your case as Distance / Time, this formula is only applicable to the movement with constant speed, or, to be more precise, it is calculating average speed.